# Calling php page in a secure way

Tags: php, android, mysql, security

I am creating a payment app for Android and using php and MySQL in Backend.

I have a PHP page where I m doing all API calls when the Android app sends a request for it.

But my concern is that if anyone discovers that link then she/he will be able to access that page will perform that task for him.

- So How can  I secure that page to be accessed by unique request by unique user?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Will this payment app be used in a real project, or are you just playing around with code?

Comment: I am just playing around. But if it will be really efficient then it can be a real product.

Comment: I would like to recommend against trying to build a payment app.

Comment: you can't, not 100% reliably anyways. any credentials/auth requirements you put on the php url would necessarily have to be in the android-side code as well. e.g. if you use http basic auth user/pass protection, then that user/pass has to be present in your app's apk somewhere, and someone could always extract it (or just sniff the data going between the device and your server). and on the php end, it'll just be seeing an http request, which means you're stuck with http-level security, which is essentially non-existent.

Comment: And if you are just playing, one of the secure ways is to enable ssl and make sure every request coming to your API has the right key, you can create public/private key for this purpose and use that in android when it makes calls to your app. Skmething to think about when talking about secure communications.

Comment: https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short - you can't be sure where a request comes from.

Your app can set a [`User-Agent`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) HTTP header *(see 14.43)*, and you can check against it on your back-end server. However this can easily be **spoofed**, and I'd recommend against doing that for pretty much any kind of back-end service.

*I'd also **strongly** recommend against coding your own payment method under any circumstance, unless you are **absolutely sure what you're doing**. And I can tell you're not, because you're asking this question. Only use APIs from trusted financial services.*